# How to wrap entire application in a tag?

Tags: react-native

I'm creating a React Native application, and I'd like to wrap all of the app's content within a tag.

I could wrap each page with the tag, but that wouldn't be a very clean solution.

```
const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
    Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
    ...
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AFApplication', () => SimpleApp);
```

What I would like working would be something like:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AFApplication', () => <DevMenuTrigger>{SimpleApp}</DevMenuTrigger>);
```

Of course the code isn't valid, but I would like to know if there is a way to get the intended effect.

Comment: @Kraylog Simpleapp isn't a component, it doesn't have a render function afaik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}
```

if yes so, please check [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html#creating-a-stack-navigator) for setup in your project.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! My code looks like `const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <DevMenuTrigger>
                <AppContainer
                    ref={nav => {
                        this.navigator = nav;
                    }}
                />
            </DevMenuTrigger>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AFApplication', () => App);` Sorry for the format :/